# Solr insatnces/nodes in solr Cloud not linking

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to setup Solr cloud with multiple instance(s), all on one machine my zookeeper ensemble is runing on local machine.

for first instance

```
bin/solr start -c -s $INSATNCE_DIR -p $solrport -z localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183 -Dsolr.log=/logs -Dsolr.install.dir=/solr-5.4.0 -V -Dbootstrap_conf=true
```

and for other instance

```
bin/solr start -c -s $INSATNCE_DIR -p $solrport -z localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183 -Dsolr.log=/logs -Dsolr.install.dir=/solr-5.4.0 -V -Dbootstrap_conf=false
```

all works fine, but each of these instance admin interface under **cloud>Tree** only lists one live node

```
localhost:8983_solr
```

not the other instances.

This is causing issue when i am creating collection to be distributed to nodeSet.

Anyone has any idea whats am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you add context root to zookeeper parameter then start servers.e.g. localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183/test..create context path using command:./<SOLR_HOME>/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost <zookeeper-nodes> -cmd makepath /test

Comment: I tried this   localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183/solr  and started solr with  /solr start -c -s $dir -p $solrport -z $ZKHOSTS  $SOLR_PARAMS -Dbootstrap_conf=$BOOTSTRAP_CONF with no effect